# Invalid connect() call unexpectedly succeeds - why?

Tags: c, sockets

I expect the following code* to fail since the server address hasn't been set with a valid value (verified in debugger - the whole struct is indeed initialized to 0, making address family AF_UNSPEC).

** incomplete illustrative snippet*

```
static struct sockaddr_in g_server_addr; 

int main(void)
{
    int hdl;

    hdl = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
    if (-1 == hdl)
    {
        printf("Client Socket creation failed.");
        return -1;
    }

    if(-1 == connect(hdl, (struct sockaddr *) &g_server_addr, sizeof(g_server_addr)))
    {
        printf("Connect() on socket failed.");
        return -1;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I need connect() to fail when called with incorrect input.
*(This code is being tested on an Ubuntu machine.)*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the connect manpage:

> Connectionless sockets may dissolve the association by connecting to an address with the sa_family member of sockaddr set to AF_UNSPEC (supported on Linux since kernel 2.2).

The manpage is a bit outdated, it will work on any socket, which can be disconnected at all, as for example TCP sockets.

In practice, there is no error when trying to dissolve the association on a stream socket, which is not yet connected. This is, why you don't get an error.

If you need to get an error, initialize the address family with an invalid family:

```
static struct sockaddr_in g_server_addr = { -1 };
```

This will yield the error `-1 EAFNOSUPPORT (Address family not supported by protocol)`

See also [`net/ipv4/af_inet.c`](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/net/ipv4/af_inet.c) of a recent linux kernel:

```
int __inet_stream_connect(struct socket *sock, struct sockaddr *uaddr,
                      int addr_len, int flags) {
...
if (uaddr->sa_family == AF_UNSPEC) {
        err = sk->sk_prot->disconnect(sk, flags);
        sock->state = err ? SS_DISCONNECTING : SS_UNCONNECTED;
        goto out;
}
...
out:
    return err;
```

Comment: This portion is valid for connectionless sockets. I initialized the socket to `SOCK_STREAM`.

Comment: @work.bin As I tried to convey, the manpage is outdated with this regard. It will also disconnect TCP sockets and not yield an error if the socket is already unconnected. I state this now a bit more explicitely

Comment: How do you know that the `connect()` man page is outdated? (not a challenge, take the question at face value) Is there a repository that I could refer to in the future for 'current' manpages?

Comment: @work.bin Check the source, I added the relevant part in the answer

Comment: Thanks for the source reference. Just as an aside, do you know what is being attempted by calling disconnect() in the connect() call for AF_UNSPEC?

Comment: @work.bin The socket is disconnected and can usually be reconnected then. For a TCP socket, this means the connection is terminated.

Comment: The upstream for (non-BSD) man pages is [the Linux man-pages project](https://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/); specifically, [`man 2 connect`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/connect.2.html), in this particular case. @Ctx: You might consider sending [a patch](https://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/patches.html) or at least [report it](https://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/reporting_bugs.html) to the maintainer.